# one to many relationships in different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

This is newbee SQL question I struggled to find a clear answer to. So please help. I have two tables in database with fields as listed below:

ConstructionProjects

- id                (unique, nonempty)
- developer         (one, nonempty)
- main_contractor   (one, nonempty)
- architect         (one, nonempty)
- (other fields)

Companies

- id                (unique, nonempty)
- projects_developed            (many or none)
- projects_as_main_contractor   (many or none)
- projects_as_architect         (many or none)
- (other fields)

So every project has only one developer, one architect and one contractor, however, it may be the same company. Any company may be involved in as many projects in any roles.

Is there a way to avoid creating 3 additional association tables to establish many to many relationships? and make 3 one to many relationships instead? 
If so, which practice is better?

*In other words, I don't understand relationships (one to many and many to many) relate (1) row to row or (2) row to "specific cell"?

- (1) if row to row then I have many to many relationships
- (2) if row to specific cell then it is multiple one to many relationships...*

I'm learning Flask_alchemy and PostgreSQL.
I ran into problem, writing a code like this (there's no reference to specific columns between tables). So this is not ok?

```
class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    constr_projects_developed = db.relationship('ConstrProject', backref='developer') 
    constr_projects_main_contracts = db.relationship('ConstrProject', backref='main_contractor')
    constr_projects_architect = db.relationship('ConstrProject', backref='architect')

class ConstrProject(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    developer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))    
    main_contractor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    architect_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
```

Then my question is, the correct way to do it is like this (1):

```
class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    constr_projects_developed = db.relationship('ConstrProject', back_populates='developer') 
    constr_projects_main_contracts = db.relationship('ConstrProject', back_populates='main_contractor')
    constr_projects_architect = db.relationship('ConstrProject', back_populates='architect')

class ConstrProject(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    developer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))    
    developer = db.relationship('Company', back_populates='constr_projects_developed')
    main_contractor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    main contractor = db.relationship('Company', back_populates='constr_projects_main_contracts')
    architect_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    architect = db.relationship('Company', back_populates='constr_projects_architect')
```

Or like this(2)?:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    cp_developed = db.relationship('Company', secondary=cp_developer_company, back_populates='developer')
    cp_main_contracts = db.relationship('Company', secondary=cp_main_contractor_company, back_populates='main_contractor')
    cp_architects = db.relationship('Company', secondary=cp_architect_company, back_populates='architect')

class ConstrProject(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    developer = db.relationship('Company', secondary=cp_developer_company, back_populates='cp_developed')
    main_contractor = db.relationship('Company', secondary=cp_main_contractor_company, back_populates='cp_main_contracts')
    architect = db.relationship('Company', secondary=cp_architect_company, back_populates='cp_architects')

cp_developer_company = db.Table('cp_developer_company'
    db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    db.Column('constr_project_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('constrproject.id'))
    )

cp_main_contractor_company = db.Table('cp_main_contractor_company'
    db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    db.Column('constr_project_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('constrproject.id'))
    )

cp_architect_company = db.Table('cp_architect_company'
    db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    db.Column('constr_project_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('constrproject.id'))
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If the developer, main_contractor and architect are the same Company, then it will have the same values. What is the problem? This is one to many relationship. To make your life easier I would pay attention to how I name these columns. I would call them: `DeveloperCompanyId`, `MainContractorCompanyId`, `ArchitectCompanyId` because it tells me you are talking about the company of the developer and tells me the value is for the `CompanyId` and if I want more info, I can look in `Company` or `Companies` table.

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't uderstand whether relationships work row-to-row or row-to-"cell"... I edited my post, added some sample code in question, maybe this clarifies my question a bit.

Comment: It works like this: *Given a value in developer column (FK), find the value in Companies.Id column. (Referenced column).* Most of the time the referenced value is the fk of the other table so one row will be found.